# Как в custom menu wordpress в тег li добавить тег a?

Tags: wordpress

Есть верстка меню, на нее нужно натянуть wordpress. Данный код создает только теги li в списке ul и выводит содержимое. А как в данный код добавить еще тег "a" внутрь тега li?

```
<ul class='list'>
  <?php
    if ( function_exists('wp_nav_menu')) {
      wp_nav_menu(
        array(
          'theme_location' => 'custom-menu',
          'fallback_cb' => 'custom-menu',
          'container' => 'ul',
          'menu_id' => 'nav',
          'menu_class' => 'nav'
          )
        );
     }
   ?>
</ul>
```

functions.php:

```
if( function_exists('register_nav_menus')) {
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'custom-menu'=>__('Custom menu'),
    )
);
}
function custom_menu() {
    wp_list_pages('title_li=&');
}
```

Верстка, которую нужно натянуть:

```
<ul class='list'>
          <li class='item'>
            <a href=''>Контакты</a>
          </li>
          <li class=''>
            <a href=''>О компании</a>
          </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ошибка, как минимум, в этой строке `'fallback_cb' => 'custom-menu',` - название функции не может быть с дефисом (и эта функция у вас объявлена с подчеркиванием)

Comment: @KAGG Design изменил я  'custom-menu'  на  'custom_menu', ситуация не изменилась

Answer (score -1):

Зарегистрировать меню (functions.php)

```
function register_menus() {
   register_nav_menus(array(
     'header-menu' => 'header-menu',
     'footer-menu' => 'footer-menu'));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_menus' );
```

Далее сформировать меню в админке вордпресса (Appearance > Menus), выбрать локацию вывода.
Вывести локацию в нужном Вам месте:

`wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'header-menu') );`